# Why $K(u)$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be an extension field of $K$ and $u\in F$.
How do we know that adjoining an element of F to K, makes $K(u)$ a field?

I know that $Q(\sqrt2)=\{a+b\sqrt2|a,b\in Q\}$ is a field, but in the general case are we guaranteed that $K(u)$ is a field?

How can this be proved

Thanks :D

Update: Following @GitGud

Let $S= \{\cap B_i|\forall i , K\cup\{u\}\subseteq B_i\}$ be the intersection of all subfields of F that contain $K∪\{u\}$.

Proof:

Since $0,1\in B_i \ \ \forall i\rightarrow 0,1\in S$

If $a \in S\rightarrow a\in B_i \ \ \forall i\rightarrow  a^{-1},-a\in B_i \ \ \forall i \rightarrow a^{-1},-a\in S$

If $a,b \in S$then $a*b^{-1}\in B_i \ \ \forall i$ and $a-b\in B_i \forall i \rightarrow$ S is closed under sums, and multiplication.
Thus $S$ is a subfield of $F$ and $S=K(u)$

Comment: Hint: How is $K(u)$ defined?

Comment: @JiK That beggs the question: why does there exist a field that has $K\cup \{u\}$ as subset.

Comment: @Jik The smallest subfield of $F$ that contains $K$ and $u$, but how are we sure such a subfield exist?

Comment: @abe15 That's easy, just take the intersection of all subfields of $F$ that contain $K\cup \{u\}$. The interesting question is when you don't have a 'larger field' (as you have $F$ here).

Comment: @GitGUD Is the quick proof ^^ good ?

Comment: I'm curious now! What exactly happens if there isn't a larger field?

Comment: I think $\mathbb{C}$ is an example

Comment: @abe15 Your proof seems fine, except for the fact that it should be $S= \bigcap\{B|K\cup\{u\}\preceq B\}$. As for the other question, I think the smallest field containing $K\cup \{u\}$ (with $u\not \in K$) is the set of expressions $\dfrac{f(u)}{g(u)}$ where $f(u),g(u)\in K[u]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to comment, but I would say that $K(u)$ is typically *defined* as the smallest field containing $K \cup \{u\}$, so taking the intersection of all subfields of $F$ with this property is really the definition of "smallest" field with that property. Then all you have to do is show the intersection of subfields is a subfield, which is straightforward.

As for your question as to "What if there isn't a bigger field?" well, it depends on your context. For one, you can always consider the algebraic closure of a field to be a "bigger" field if yours isn't algebraically closed, which exists for any field by Zorn's lemma. If your field is algebraically closed, like $\mathbb{C}$, then $\mathbb{C}(u)$ can be thought of as a field extension where $u$ is some symbol defined to be transcendental over $\mathbb{C}$. Then this would be all rational functions in $u$ over $\mathbb{C}$. I would suggest reading about function fields if this interests you.